# Request scoped attributes in session scoped bean JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

The application that I'm working on uses a huge legacy bean that is session scoped. The problem is I can't refactor the code and I need some attributes to be request scoped. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: A concrete example might improve the quality of your question and elicit more answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a `@RequestScoped` bean, inject the legacy session scoped bean by using [`@ManagedProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedProperty.html) and use [`@PostConstruct`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) to retrieve the attributes you need.

For example:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "legacyBean")
@SessionScoped
public class LegacyBean implements Serializable {
    private Object attr1;
    private Object attr2;

    // Getters and setters
}

@ManagedBean(name = "requestScopedBean")
@RequestScoped
public class RequestScopedBean {
    private Object requestAttr1;

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{legacyBean}")
    private LegacyBean legacyBean;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        this.requestAttr1 = legacyBean.getAttr1();
    }

    public Object getRequestAttr1() {
        return this.requestAttr1 ;
    }
}
```